# Error scalar subquery querying json file in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am beginner in bigquery! I have this json file in bigquery:

[image]

I want to unnest all columns and I am trying the following query:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(list)) 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

I have already read all others posts with the same error above but none of them helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT city.*,
       sys.pod, clouds.all, list.dx_txt, weather.description, weather.icon, weather.main
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(list.weather) weather, UNNEST(list.sys) sys, UNNEST(list.clouds) clouds
```

Comment: is not working your query. I am getting this error: "Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<lon FLOAT64, lat FLOAT64>"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `List` is an `ARRAY` of `STRUCT`, while `city` is just a `STRUCT`. Please make sure you make an effort explaining the details/types of your table columns along with the rationale of your question on SO.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    city.id as city_id,
    city.sunset as sunset,
    city.country as country, 
    city.timezone as timezone, 
    city.name as name, 
    city.coord.lon as lon, 
    city.coord.lat as lat, 
    city.sunrise as sunrise, 
    weather.description,
    weather.icon,
    weather.main,
    list.dt_txt,
    list.clouds.all,
    list.sys.pod
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(list) as list, UNNEST(list.weather) as weather
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what do you mean by "rationale of your question on SO"? After little adjustments in your code I am getting this error in field list.dx_txt: "Field name dx_txt does not exist in STRUCT<sys STRUCT<pod STRING>, clouds STRUCT<`all` INT64>, dt_txt TIMESTAMP, ...>; Did you mean dt_txt? at [14:9]" This field has type: TIMESTAMP, Mode: NULLABLE and Description:bq-datetime. I am looking up how to fix but I have not found any answer yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I made a fix. Let me know if it works. By the 'rationale of your question', I meant the objective behind your query (like what would you like to achieve in the output, whats the expected output, what is the table schema, etc.), which makes it easier to answer the question as compared to looking at a screenshot to determine column types.

Comment: you put the same code! Where is the difference compared with the code you put the first time? I explained thats not working properly! Thats why I did an adjustment and now is only with one error:"Field name dx_txt does not exist in STRUCT<sys STRUCT<pod STRING>, clouds STRUCT<`all` INT64>, dt_txt TIMESTAMP, ...>; Did you mean dt_txt? at [14:9]" in the field "list.dt_txt". You have understood perfectly what I need based upon the image and your answer so, I guess there is no need more details. Thank you anyway. Best Regards

Comment: Because in the screenshot you posted, your column name looks like `dt_txt`, which I have changed now in my answer. When I said you need to be more explicit and detailed in terms of what you want to ask, you really have to work on your question and explain things like your column types, their names, your nested structure etc. instead of simply posting a half-visible screenshot and letting people guess about it.